# Aid with bootstrap popover

Tags: html

I have this button where I want the popover to be displayed on click, but it isn't working. Can anybody help?

External links included

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Button

```html
<button class="buttonsprize" id="bookmark1" name="bookmark1" data-html="true" data-toggle="popover" title="Popover Header" data-content="Some content inside the popover" style="padding:14px;">
 <div style="text-align:center;"><i class="fas fa-bookmark"></i></div>
</button>
```

Javascript

```
<script>
$(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover(); 
});
</script>
```

Comment: can you show an example of how you want your popup

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function () {
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()
})
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" data-toggle="popover" title="Popover title" data-content="This is bootstrap popover"> popover</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Can you please try this code.You can use popover like this. :)